# Celery countdown error

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to add a countdown to a task but with no luck.

Here is the code I am using

```
@celery.task
def check_st(key, t):
    device = Device.query.filter(Device.key == key).first()
    data = Data.query.filter(Data.dev_id == device.id).order_by(Data.timestamp.desc()).first()
    if(data.timestamp == t):
        return True
```

and I am calling it like that

```
check_st.apply_async([key, data.timestamp], countdown=300)
```

Taken from the full [celery log](http://pastebin.com/CEyLy5QH).

Any ideas?

### EDIT

Testing a simple example with countdown seems to work fine. I guess it is my project layout that causes the problem combined with the way I run celery.

So my layout is like this

proj(app(`__init__.py`, `views.py`, `models.py`, `tasks.py`))

In my tasks.py I import modules like this

```
from app.models import Device, Data
```

then in my views.py I import the tasks using

```
from app.tasks import check_st
```

and I run celery in directory `proj/` like this

```
celery -A app.tasks worker -l info
```

Every other task is working as expected with this setup but when I add the countdown keyword i get the following

```
Task app.tasks.check_st[deffd607-c6d4-41af-882c-e111736888ba] raised exception: TypeError("check_st() got an unexpected keyword argument 'countdown'",)
```

Comment: first = datetime.datetime(year, month, 1, hour, minute) <--is this line of code in your script? 
"ValueError: month must be in 1..12" Seems like an invalid input error..

Comment: There is nothing like this in my code.

Comment: The log you linked to is executing a *different* task: `Got task from broker: app.tasks.c
heck_fence[5b28c53e-c842-4957-bed2-2d53ed0ec00a]`.

Comment: And it is being thrown by the `task.eta` value.

Comment: @MartijnPieters this task is executed before check_st. It is not the one causing the problem cause if I remove the check_st execution it works as expected.

Comment: @marcushatchenson: And if your function was changed to return `None`? or didn't do *anything*? What happens then? It is not necessarily what your function does that breaks things.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didn't make this clear. If I remove the keyword `countdown` everything is ok. If I add it I get this error.

Comment: Ah, I indeed missed that. The countdown is translated into an ETA value, and that is going wrong here. It *could* be a bug in Celery here, where the ETA and your timezone are interacting badly.

Comment: Edited my question cause I had other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved finally. The solution came by changing

```
celery -A app.tasks worker -l info
```

to

```
celery --workdir=proj/ -A app.tasks worker -l info
```